# Company-wide chatter access through REST api

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-chatter

I am examining the REST api for the chatter system in Salesforce, but I am not finding all of the features that I am hoping for.  It appears that all access must be through a single user's oauth.  Is it possible to establish company-wide access to chatter?  The main use case is that I want to be able to post alerts from my system onto the company chatter feed.  These alerts do not come from a specific user, but rather come from the system as a whole.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is done in the context of a user, what I've seen done is to give these systems a dedicated user account, for example we have a user called Jenkins that our Jenkins build server uses to post build results to chatter.

Comment: Do you have to pay for a separate Jenkins user?

Comment: If all its doing it posting to chatter, then you can use a chatter free user for the account